# ios determine how an app is launched

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, launching-application

Is there any way to determine "how" an app is launched or made active (i.e. homescreen tap, four finger swipe, siri, etc...)?

There's this thread which is similar ([Determining whether iOS application was launched via Siri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149587/determining-whether-ios-application-was-launched-via-siri)), however not too many answers in this. There's also this for Mac OSX ([How can a Mac app determine the method used to launch it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812371/how-can-a-mac-app-determine-the-method-used-to-launch-it)) but I need something similar for iOS.

I've also skimmed through this (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3) though I coudn't find anything that recognizes "how" the app was launched.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can figure out that an app was launched from a URL in another application using the AppDelegate method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation { }
```

Additionally, `application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` has options, which are keys that you can find [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Launch_Options_Keys) that tell you reasons why the app launched.

Those keys are:

```
NSString *const UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey;
NSString *const UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey;
NSString *const UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey;
NSString *const UIApplicationLaunchOptionsAnnotationKey;
NSString *const UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey;
NSString *const UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey;
NSString *const UIApplicationLaunchOptionsNewsstandDownloadsKey;
NSString *const UIApplicationLaunchOptionsBluetoothCentralsKey;
NSString *const UIApplicationLaunchOptionsBluetoothPeripheralsKey;
```

You can check for them with if statements when the app launches.

Comment: But won't this only tell me when the app is launched via URL? How does this work with four finger swipe?